# XSLT 2.0 using key with except returns unexpected result

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

NB: title changed to reflect the problem better.

My xml documents contain an element `<tei:seg @type @xml:id @corresp>` which wrap little 'stories'. The attribute `@corresp` allows me to connect these stories to a master story. For example, these `seg` are all connected by their `@corresp`:

```
doc1.xml//seg[@type='dep_event' @corresp='#JKL' @xml:id='doc1-05']
doc2.xml//seg[@type='dep_event' @corresp='#JKL' @xml:id='doc2-06']
doc6.xml//seg[@type='dep_event' @corresp='#JKL' @xml:id='doc6-03']
```

My objective is: when the XSLT template finds a `@corresp`, find other   `seg` in other documents with the same `@corresp` and output their respective `@xml:id``

So, in the above example, if the current `seg` was `@xml:id='doc1-05'`, the template outputs a list: `Corresponds to doc2-06, doc6-03`

Until I can solve the [current problems with XSLT collection()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934971/exist-loading-xslt-exception-thrown-by-uriresolver) in eXist-DB, I'm falling back on my previous solution: a 'TEI corpus' xml document which maintains a master list of all related tei-xml documents via `xi:include`. This way I provide a single document node whereby the processor can access and search all the xml documents.

So, I declare the corpus document:

```
<xsl:variable name="corpus" select="doc('ms609_corpus.xml')"/>
```

Then create a `key` for the `@corresp`:

```
<xsl:key name="correspkey" match="//tei:seg[@type='dep_event' and @corresp]" use="@corresp"/>
```

Then I use the key with the `doc()` to search:

```
<xsl:when test="tei:seg[@type='dep_event' and @corresp]">
     <xsl:variable name="correspvar" 
        select="data(self::seg[@type='dep_event' and @corresp]/@corresp)"/>
     <xsl:text>Corresponds to </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="data($corpus/(key('correspkey',$correspvar) except $correspvar)/@xml:id)" separator=", "/>
</xsl:when>
```

It returns the results, but the `except` should exclude the current `@corresp`. Yet it is included in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `except` operator works on sequences of nodes based on node identity, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#combining_seq defining

> The except operator takes two node sequences as operands and returns a
>   sequence containing all the nodes that occur in the first operand but
>   not in the second operand ... All these operators eliminate duplicate
>   nodes from their result sequences based on node identity

Based on that I think you simply want

```
 <xsl:value-of select="$corpus/(key('correspkey', current()/@corresp) except current())/@xml:id)" separator=", "/>
```

Using `data` on nodes which atomizes nodes to values and then trying to use `except` which works on nodes doesn't seem to make sense to me.